# Android: NullPointerException using findFragmentById() after ugrading support libraries

Tags: android, android-appcompat, fragmentmanager

I just switched an old Android project from Eclipse to Android Studio and in that process I updated from the old support libraries version `19.0.1` to `22.2.0`. After this I get some errors in my previously working code. I dowloaded all SDKs in between and checked where the error first came into play, and it seems to be in version `21.1.0` and above. I looked in the [release notes](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) for that version, but could not find anything of interest.

My error is that I am getting a `NullPointerException` here. Note that this method is part of the `Activity`, not the parent `Fragment`.

```
public synchronized void onRecipesFiltered(ArrayList<Recipe> filteredRecipes)
{   
    FilteredRecipesListFragment filteredRecipesListFragment = (FilteredRecipesListFragment)
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mm_filtered_recipes_list_fragment);

    // filteredRecipesListFragment becomes null
    filteredRecipesListFragment.onRecipesFiltered(filteredRecipes);
}
```

The `Fragment` I am getting here is a `ListFragment` which is part of an XML file which is inflated at the startup of the app. It seems like this `ListFragment` is added to a `FragmentManager` *inside* the parent `Fragment` during inflation. This is probably why I get a nullpointer while getting the `FragmentManager` of the `Activity`. Thus, my question is:

How can I get the `ListFragment` in the `Activity`? Is it necessary to keep a reference to the parent `Fragment` to get the `ListFragment` through its `FragmentManager`? The parent `Fragment` is inflated when returning `new MyFragment()` in `FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem()`, nowhere else, hence it is a bit more tricky to get the proper reference in the `Activity`.

There is one more thing that should be noted: I saw some messages telling me I should updated to `JDK 1.7`, which I did (`OpenJDK 1.7`). I don't remember what I did, but under "External Libraries" I see `<1.7> (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64)`. Not sure if this matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261142/1139324) answer. It seems like it is not really possible to get the `Fragment`s from the `ViewPager` in a pretty way, hence they must be kept as references after creation and fetched when required.

I copy the main code of the answer here, just in case. The main idea is to keep the `Fragment`s in the `SparseArray` to fetch them when needed. They must be inserted and removed after creation/before removal.

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ...;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return MyFragment.newInstance(...); 
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }
}
```

After doing this I could rewrite my method to the following, using `getChildFragmentManager()` as noted by @Skizo:

```
public synchronized void onRecipesFiltered(ArrayList<Recipe> filteredRecipes)
{
    MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter = (MyPagerAdapter) mMyViewPager.getAdapter();
    FilteredRecipesFragment filteredRecipesFragment = (FilteredRecipesFragment)
            myPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(PagerConstants.PAGE_FILTER_RECIPES);

    if (filteredRecipesFragment == null)
    {
        // Fragments that has not yet been instantiated will be returned as null. Cannot do anything about it.
        // Should be fairly unlikely. See:
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261142/1139324
        return;
    }

    FilteredRecipesListFragment listFragment = (FilteredRecipesListFragment)
            filteredRecipesFragment.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mm_filtered_recipes_list_fragment);
    listFragment.onRecipesFiltered(filteredRecipes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace :

```
FilteredRecipesListFragment filteredRecipesListFragment = (FilteredRecipesListFragment)
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mm_filtered_recipes_list_fragment);
```

to :

```
 FilteredRecipesListFragment filteredRecipesListFragment = (FilteredRecipesListFragment)
    getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mm_filtered_recipes_list_fragment);
```

Read more about `getChildFragmentManager()` on the [getChildFragmentManager() documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager())

Comment: This means that I have to keep a reference to the parent `Fragment` somewhere to be able to call `getChildFragmentManager()`. The method in the question is placed in the `Activity` to act as a gateway between the `Activity` and its `Fragments`. I *could* keep a reference to the parent `Fragment`, but this is part of a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, hence it is not so easy to hold a reference because `FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem()` returns `new FilteredRecipesFragment()`. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm out of ideas... let me think about that